# Building a datasource object from SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Did a quick search on SO, couldn't find what I need:

I am in process of trying out a new control suite (DevExpress ASP) and need to bind the [TabStrip](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/TabControl/Features.aspx) control to a datasource from SQL. The [online documentation](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/TabControl/DataBinding.aspx) states that *"any object that implements the IHierarchicalEnumerable or IHierarchicalDataSource interface (e.g. SiteMapDataSource, XmlDataSource) may be used as a data source for this control. "*

Having no experience with interfaces, How do I put my stored proc's XML results into an object as described by the documentation?

ps: I have NO LINQ experience either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a data source that allows transforming your data to an hierarchical structure. Here [is an interesting example](http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/ViewPost.aspx?PostID=238) of an implementation of an IHierarchicalDataSource that allows browsing the file system. It might give you an idea of how to do this.

Good luck.

Comment: The internet is a collection of broken links. Fredrik Normen moved his blog to [weblogs.asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen), but it seems that he didn't migrate that specific article. I'm afraid that the article doesn't exist anymore.